# Android deep links url pattern

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to include deep links handle in my Android app. But I can't find how we can register only some patterns of urls? For example, I want my app open only if the url contains "london" keyword in it. How can I implement this? Something like this:

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


            <data android:host="www.mysite.com" android:pathPrefix="/*/london/*" android:scheme="https" />
```

Comment: Did you try this ? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw&t=0s

Comment: This is not cover the situation with www.mysite.com/ukraine/{anyValue}/londont/{any values}